# Routing the dropdown option in angular2

Tags: angular

i have created a dropdown list for 4 option as..

[image: This is my Dropdown list]

I have to route this option such as when i click the option A then it should route to **`A.ts`** and same for the B to B.ts C to C.ts  and D to D.ts

```
My app.ts 
import {bootstrap}  from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NGL_DIRECTIVES, provideNglConfig} from 'ng-lightning/ng-lightning';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [NGL_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: 'app/angular-2-menu.html',


})
export class Angular2Menu {

 open: boolean;
  picks: any[] = [];

  items = [
    { value: 'A' },
    { value: 'B' },
    { value: 'C' },
    { value: 'D' },
  ];

  onToggle($event: Event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.open = true;
  }

}

bootstrap(Angular2Menu, [provideNglConfig()]);
```

and
app/angular-2-menu.html as

```
and my--> **app/angular-2-menu.html**


<div style="padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px">
<div class="slds-text-heading--label slds-m-bottom--small">Angular 2 Dropdown Menu</div>
<span nglDropdown [(open)]="open">
  <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" nglDropdownTrigger>
    <span class="slds-truncate">Select an item</span>
    <ngl-icon icon="down" size="x-small"></ngl-icon>
  </button>
  <div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown--left">
    <ul class="dropdown__list" role="menu">
      <li class="slds-dropdown__item" *ngFor="#item of items;">
        <a role="menuitem" nglDropdownItem (click)="selected = item.value; open = false;">
          <p class="slds-truncate">{{item.value}}</p>
          <ngl-icon [icon]="item.icon" size="x-small"></ngl-icon>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</span>
```

Please guide me with that..

Comment: You should follow the 'echonax' what he said but replace the (click) event to (onChange) check this how it works on angular2.

Comment: Can you please provide one plunker example for this so i can understand this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a method to your click event

```
 <a role="menuitem" nglDropdownItem (click)="onAnchorClick($event)">
```

and do the navigation like this inside your component:

```
onAnchorClick(item){
    this.selected = item.value; 
    this.open = false;
    switch(this.selected){
        case "A": 
          this.router.navigate(["/A"]);
          break;
        case "B":
          ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items = [
    { value: 'A' , url : '/A'},
    { value: 'B' , url : '/B'},
    { value: 'C' , url : '/C'},
    { value: 'D' , url : '/D'},
  ];




<a role="menuitem" nglDropdownItem  [routerLink]="['' + item.url]" (click)="selected = item.value; open = false;">
  </a>
```

Comment: Showing an error as....EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "a" ("ncate">{{item.value}}</p>
          <ngl-icon [icon]="item.icon" size="x-small"></ngl-icon>
        [ERROR ->]</a>
  <!--<a role="menuitem" nglDropdownItem  [routerLink]="['' + item.url]" (click)="selected = ite"): Angular2Menu@13:8